# Does node.js have any libraries for talking to SignalR Hubs?

Tags: api, http, node.js, signalr

I'd like to build a frontend web-application using node, talking to an intermediate API that's probably built with .NET tools.  Since SignalR is the most likely candidate for building an HTTP Push API, I'd like to know whether there's already a library for node to talk to it, or whether I'll have to figure something out myself (I'm new-ish to both).

Comment: 'frontend web-application using node' Node is client-side.. are you making a web app that talks to node which then talks to the signalr? why not just write a webapp that talks to signalr?

Comment: node is server-side.  I'm making a server-side web-app which will use nowjs and socket.io to talk to the browser, but am constrained by our system guidelines to only talk to a set of internal APIs to interact with the rest of the system (eg, get/set data, etc).  The node app does not have direct database access, only via the API-set.

Comment: So you want your node backend code to talk to a SignalR server?

Comment: @ElleryFamilia yes, but both ways.  That is SignalR -> node, and node -> SignalR.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://github.com/maartenba/SignalR.Node